# OKTA SAML integration with AngularJs application

Tags: okta

How to read SAML response XML in Javascript code?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and then point out specifically what doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am trying to figure out a way to read SAML response within AngularJS code.